# Can rapid eye blinking induce epileptic seizures?

Tags: neuroscience, vision, neurology

Photosensitive epilepsies are characterized by visually-induced seizures. Flashing-light stimuli are known to induce seizures in some (but not all) patients. My question is whether people with this type of epilepsy can self-induce seizures by rapid eye blinking?

Comment: I'd guess not - a [strobe light's pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobe_light) can last a few milliseconds, while a [blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink) can last a hundred times as long.

Comment: Photosensitive epilepsy is often evoked at flicker frequencies of 3-30 Hz, which should be feasible through eye blinking. However, I couldn't find any info on self-induced seizures, and it is not listed in common causes of flash-induced seizures. E.g.: http://www.epilepsysociety.org.uk/. More common causes are computer games, TV screens etc.

Comment: @Bez and others - Why is this question put on hold? There isn't any self-referral present? I find it rather interesting and couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: This is an interesting question and NOT a personal medical question!

Comment: @ChrisStronks reopened for your pleasure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Self-induction” in photosensitive epilepsy is a well-described and fascinating  phenomenon. Photosensitivity itself is rare, [occurring in only ~5% of patients with epilepsy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=renite+KN.+Photosensitivity+in+epilepsy%3A+electrophysiological+and+clinical+correlates.+Acta+Neurologica+Scandinavica+1989%3B+80+%28Suppl+125%29%3A3%E2%80%93149).<sup>1</sup> Among this group it [has been estimated](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12169155)<sup>2</sup> that 25% self-induce epileptiform activity. The most common methods appear to be passing a hand with open fingers repeatedly across the visual field and, as you query, blinking.

Quoting from a classical paper on the topic by [Andermann et al](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=13861141):<sup>3</sup>

> The method of inducing seizures varies
>   both in detail and in principle. Light contrasts are always brought about, but they may either be applied to and alternate for the whole visual field—an effect produced by blinking or batting the eyelids and induced by any flickering light—or else the attack is elicited by the spatial displacement of brightness and darkness  over the retina.

This phenomenon is most common in epileptics with established photic triggers, and the scenario triggering an attack is often in the context of bright sunlight. However, this has also been described in epileptics who are not otherwise photosensitive. See, for example, [“Seizures triggered by blinking in a non-photosensitive epileptic.”](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=3084713)<sup>4</sup>
Notably, some authors have questioned whether blinking and other “triggers” are actually themselves ictal phenomena (i.e. representing the initial phase of an epileptic event) rather than a form of voluntary self-induction. For more on that hypothesis, see [Ames, 1971](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=5132972).<sup>5</sup>

Presuming that this is, in fact, self-induction as has been traditionally postulated, the question of why such patients repeatedly self-induce seizures is perhaps the most interesting aspect of this. There [has been some research](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12169155)<sup>2</sup> considering the psychiatric factors underlying the behavior. Quoting [Andermann](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=13861141)<sup>3</sup> again:

> The reward a patient seeks by self-stimulation may lie in escape from unwanted situations, in attracting attention, in punishing those around him, or, indeed, in deriving pleasure from the attack.

---

References

1. Kasteleijn-Nolst Trenité DG. *Photosensitivity in epilepsy. Electrophysiological and clinical correlates.* Acta Neurol Scand Suppl. 1989;125:3-149.
2. Ng BY. *Psychiatric aspects of self-induced epileptic seizures.* Aust N Z J Psychiatry. 2002 Aug;36(4):534-43.
3. Andermann K, et al. *Self-induced epilepsy. A collection of self-induced epilepsy cases compared with some other photoconvulsive cases.* Arch Neurol. 1962 Jan;6:49-65.
4. Rafal RD, Laxer KD, Janowsky JS. *Seizures triggered by blinking in a non-photosensitive epileptic.* J Neurol Neurosurg Psychiatry. 1986 Apr;49(4):445-7.
5. Ames FR. *"Self-induction" in photosensitive epilepsy.* Brain. 1971;94(4):781-98.